# Store data in cache for 30 min MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action in my MVC controller, and I want to cache its return result on the basis of passed parameters as a key, so that next time this action will be called it will first look in cache if not found it will look in Data storage.

```
 public ActionResult GetSearchResult(string zipcode, int pageSize, int currentPage)
 {
     Cache[zipcode + page + currentpage] = somedata // but it should be cleared after 30 min
 }
```

How can I do this? I can store the data in the cache object, as above, but I want to ensure that cached objects are cleared after 30 minutes. I can't see how to configure the lifetime either on a global or per-cached-object basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suggest using the outputcache filter on your action, rather than doing it manually yourself

```
     [OutputCache(Duration=1800, VaryByParam="*")]
     public ActionResult GetSearchResult(string zipcode, int pageSize, int currentPage)
     {
  //       Cache[zipcode + page + currentpage] = somedata // but it should be cleared after 30 min
     }
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but will it stores data as per the changing parameters value basis? because zipcode will keep changing?

Comment: You mean will it cache different results for different input zip codes? Yes, that's what the [`VaryByParam`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.varybyparam.aspx) property specifies

Comment: @Rup hit the nail on the head. You can use VaryByParam to cache using specific, all or no parameters. In my example I'm saying that the zipcode,pagesize and currentPage (i.e. all parameters) should be used to determine what to cache (and pull from the cache)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Cache.Insert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.insert.aspx) method.

```
Cache.Insert("key", myTimeSensitiveData, null, 
  DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), TimeSpan.Zero);
```

See [ASP.NET Caching: Techniques and Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx#aspnet-cachingtechniquesbestpract_topic4) for more information.